# Get last section of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a input field with a name attribute like `field[subkey][subkey2]`

How can I get the last part of the string, `subkey2` in javascript?

```
$('input').each(function(){
 var name = $(this).attr('name');

 // here I need only the last part of "name"

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thoughts:

```
var string = "field[subkey][subkey2]",
    parts = string.split('['),
    variable2 = parts[2].substring(0,parts[2].length - 1);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zkpsw/).

Alternatively:

```
var string = "field[subkey][subkey2]",
    variable2 = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('[') + 1,string.length - 1);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zkpsw/1/).

If you want to use jQuery to select the relevant elements:

```
$('input').each(
    function() {
        var string = this.name;
        $(this).val(string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('[') + 1, string.length - 1));
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zkpsw/3/).

References:

- [`string.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).
- [`string.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`string.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Answer (score 2):

```
"field[subkey][subkey2]".match(/\[([^\]]*)\]$/)[1]
//"subkey2"
```

Comment: This is the best answer, but instead of selecting [1], a `.pop()` seems cleaner

Answer (score 1):

```
str='field[subkey][subkey2]';
spl=str.split('][');
new_str=spl.pop();
final=new_str.substr(0,new_str.length-1);

//final=subkey2
```

in case you have a variable depth